# Splitting url parameter node.js?

Tags: node.js

I am having the following url parameter

**sample value actual value contains so many parameters**

```
var data = "browserName=MSIE&cookies=Rgn=%7CCode%3DMUMBAI%7Ctext%3DMumbai%7C; NREUM=s=1376355292394&r=220970&p=2080092;cs_uuid=209712058942163; cs_si=209712058942163.1&javascriptEnabled=true";
```

Following function is used to get the particular parameter

//Generic Function to get particular parameter

```
getParameterValue : function(data, parameter) {

    var value = null;
    if (data.length > 0) {
        var paramArray = data.split("&");

        for ( var i = 0; len = paramArray.length, i < len; i++) {
            var param = paramArray[i];
            var splitter = parameter + "=";
            if (param.indexOf(splitter) > -1) {
                value = param.substring(param.indexOf(splitter)
                        + splitter.length, param.length);
                break;
            }

        }
    }
    return value;
```

}

Example

```
 getParameterValue(data, "browserName");

 output is MSIE //correct
```

**Problem is**

```
getParameterValue(data, "cookies");

Output is

Rgn=%7CCode%3DMUMBAI%7Ctext%3DMumbai%7C; NREUM=s=1376355292394
```

But required output is

```
Rgn=%7CCode%3DMUMBAI%7Ctext%3DMumbai%7C; NREUM=s=1376355292394&r=220970&p=2080092;cs_uuid=209712058942163; cs_si=209712058942163.1
```

**To Know :**

1.URL parameter is encoded(clientside) while sending to node server and decoded.

2.NREUM is not encoded, So getParameterValue method splits upto 1376355292394.

Any help to improve `getParameterValue` function.

Ready to explain more.

Comment: Why exactly isn't NREUM URL encoded? That would solve your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, `getParameterValue()` does seem to be parsing `data` correctly, but `data` is not encoded properly to distinguish between delimiters and value characters.

The value of `cookies`, for example:

```
cookies=Rgn=%7CCode%3DMUMBAI%7Ctext%3DMumbai%7C; NREUM=s=1376355292394&r=220970&p=2080092;cs_uuid=209712058942163; cs_si=209712058942163.1
```

Should itself be encoded (on top of any encoding used for the cookie values themselves).

```
cookies=Rgn%3D%257CCode%253DMUMBAI%257Ctext%253DMumbai%257C%3B%20NREUM%3Ds%3D1376355292394%26r%3D220970%26p%3D2080092%3Bcs_uuid%3D209712058942163%3B%20cs_si%3D209712058942163.1
```

And, it's rather late to try to "*fix*" this server-side because of the ambiguity. It'll need to be encoded client-side, which can be done with [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

```
'cookies=' + encodeURIComponent(cookies)
```

---

If you happen to be using jQuery, you can use [`jQuery.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) to help ensure proper encoding.

```
var data = {
    browserName: 'MSIE',
    cookies: document.cookie,
    javascriptEnabled: true
};

data = $.param(data); // browserName=MSIE&cookies=Rgn%3D%257CCode...
```

Or, you can use a light-weight recreation, at least for the "*traditional*" format.

```
function urlParam(params) {
    var res = [];

    for (var name in params) {
        res.push(encodeURIComponent(name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(params[name]));
    }

    return res.join('&');
}

var data = urlParam(data);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/GQpTB/

---

Also, are you aware that Node.js has [`querystring.parse()`](http://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html#querystring_querystring_parse_str_sep_eq_options)?

```
// with: var qs = require('querystring');
var query = qs.parse(data);

console.log(query.cookies); // ...
```

Comment: @karthick.k, use NodeJS' querystring module and encode everything properly client side.